# Laravel - Configuring redis for ShouldBroadcast interface

Tags: php, redis, laravel-5

I am trying Event Broadcasting in Laravel 5.1!

How do I configure redis to connect to a different port, host and password? I tried this. Doesn't work!

*app/broadcasting.php*

```
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => [
         'host' => '127.5.84.2',
         'port' => 16379,
         'password' => 'ZTNiMGM0NDI5OG'
    ],
],
```